# Nvidia driver does not install

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I upgraded kernel of my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 4.0.5 and when I try to install video drivers

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

I get this error:

```
Building initial module for 4.0.4-040004-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.0.4-040004-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.0.4-040004-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304/304.125/build/make.log for more information.
```

What's the matter ?

```
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0551
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: You have an unsupported kernel for this driver.

Comment: what do my doing ?

Comment: Just boot with a supported kernel and driver will install. What was the reason of installing 4.0.5?

Comment: because often cresh and should restart , when update his  system never cresh.

Comment: when ubuntu 15 install ,  montior black and just mouse move

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep EA2 'VGA|3D` terminal command.

Comment: [code]engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ lspci -k | grep EA2 VGA|3D
grep: VGA: No such file or directory
3D: command not found
[/code]

Comment: Sorry for a typo. It is `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D`. But post it TO YOUR QUESTION. Not to comments.

Comment: can i have your email addreess ?

Comment: If the solution worked, please add some words on what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend installing proprietary Nvidia drivers for 9xxx adapters.

They are not supported well by new Nvidia drivers.

I suggest keep using open source nouveau.

As an alternative you can use nvidia-304 drivers, but they will not build for the installed 4.0.4 kernel.

You can try to install nvidia-340 from Ubuntu 15.04 repository by running

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

But they may not build for your custom kernel.

You can also try to install same 340 driver from xorg-edgers. It may or may not build for your kernel, but you need to learn uninstalling drivers from console, because GUI may not load after you install this drivers.

Drivers from ppa can be installed this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: @Mehdi Please comment which of alternative solutions worked for you.

Comment: i think using nouveau better nvidia but while it test for matter cresh. @pilot6 thanks you